# How to access the array elements

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

```
var count:uint = 0;
var textInputs:Array /* of TextInputs */ = [];
for(var i:String in columnsData){
    textInputs[count] = new TextInput();

    addChild(textInputs[count]);
    count++;
}
```

here how can i access the first, second of Array of textinputs in the form of string or any thing to further proceed

Comment: what's wrong with textInputs[0].text and textInputs[1].text?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood what your question is, but you're not setting the value for text inputs:

I prefer it the following way:

```
//make the array an instance variable instead of local var
//so that it can be accessed from other functions if required.
public var textInputs:Array = [];

for(var str:String in columnsData)
{
  var ti:TextInput = new TextInput();
  ti.text = str;
  addChild(ti);
  textInputs.push(ti);
}
```

You can access the values using `textInputs[0].text` etc.

```
if(textInput != null){
  for(var i:Number = 0; i < textInputs.length; i++)
    trace(textInputs[i].text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(getChildAt(0) as TextInput).text //first
(getChildAt(1) as TextInput).text //second
```

If your sprite contains something other than TextInput at indices 0 & 1 you'll get null reference exception.

Comment: this getChildAt comes under..?

Comment: public function ContinclickHandler():void {

    if(contin.label == "Continue") {
        Alert.show("Inside");
        //first
        Alert.show(fieldInputs[0].text.toString());
    }
}

So here I am accessing fieldInputs[0] in separate function but I cant show it flex script but the inside message in Alert is coming why not fieldinputs

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- dpcontrols\UseIList.mxml -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    initialize="initData();">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.*;

            // The data provider is an Array of Strings
            public var myArray:Array = ["AZ", "MA", "MZ", "MN", "MO", "MS"];
            // Declare an ArrayList that represents the Array.
            [Bindable]
            public var myAL:ArrayList;

            //Initialize the ArrayList.
            public function initData():void {
                myAL = new ArrayList(myArray); 
            }

            // The function to change the collection, and therefore
            // the Array.
            public function changeCollection():void {
                // Get the original collection length. 
                var oldLength:int=myAL.length;

                // Remove the invalid first item, AZ.
                var removedItem:String=String(myAL.removeItemAt(0));
                // Add ME as the second item. (ILists used 0-based indexing.)
                myAL.addItemAt("ME", 1);
                // Add MT at the end of the Array and collection.
                myAL.addItem("MT");
                // Change the third item from MZ to MI.
                myAL.setItemAt("MI", 2);
                // Get the updated collection length. 
                var newLength:int=myAL.length;
                // Get the index of the item with the value ME.
                var addedItemIndex:int=myAL.getItemIndex("ME");
                // Get the fifth item in the collection.
                var index4Item:String=String(myAL.getItemAt(4));

                // Display the information in the TextArea control.
                ta1.text="Start Length: " + oldLength + ". New Length: " +
                    newLength;
                ta1.text+=".\nRemoved " + removedItem;
                ta1.text+=".\nAdded ME at index " + addedItemIndex;
                ta1.text+=".\nThe item at index 4 is " + index4Item + ".";
                // Show that the base Array has been changed.
                ta1.text+="\nThe base Array is: " + myArray.join();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ComboBox id="myCB" dataProvider="{myAL}"/>
    <s:TextArea id="ta1" height="75" width="300"/> 
    <s:Button label="rearrange list" click="changeCollection();"/>
</s:Application>
```